# Sql Data Validation - multiple conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I currently work on a project that needs to create some PowerBi reports based on sql queries, so I need to validate the data type of the recorded data. I know what data type should be, I just need to check if the results found by the query matches the db data type.

I have a query that works, with multiple conditions, but the problem is that it stops checking the condition, when it finds the first viable type. I need the query to check all the conditions and then chose the appropriate one.

P.S I'm using Amazon Redshift

here is my query:

```
select event_name,
json_extract_path_text(event_params, 'avg_lat') as avg_lat,
case when avg_lat ~ ('[0-9]') AND len(avg_lat) and <= 4 then 'Integer'
    when avg_lat ~ ('[0-9]')  AND len(avg_lat) between 5 and 17 then 'Number'
    when avg_lat ~ ('[0-9a-z]') or avg_lat ~ ('[0-9A-Z]') then 'String'
    when avg_lat ~ 'True' or avg_lat ~ 'False' then 'Boolean'
    when avg_lat ~ ('%.%') then 'Float' end as avg_lat_data_type
from xxxxx
where title_id in ('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
and event_name= 'connection'
and dt= current_date -3
```

Thank you.
Alex

Comment: What do you mean with stop checking, do you mean that one row from `avg_lat` can contain several different types?

Comment: Also from what I see (I have not worked with Amazon Redshit) it looks like your patterns are only matching 1 character in `avg_lat`, so for instance "ab1c" would be considered an Integer. Shouldn't the pattern be something like `'^[0-9]*$'`? for integers?

Comment: By "stops checking" I mean that if the row fulfils the first condition, the query doesn't checks further.
Also, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to add some sample data and expected result to further explain what you want

Comment: I don't know how to add images here -.-

https://imgur.com/a/R1fVjKZ